# Will I get the entire VM machine with all installation?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

If I created a VM Azure machine and setup/installed all required nodejs, npm modules, IIS, mongoDb. on basis on my usages I shut down the VM machine. After start the VM machine, Will I get the entire machine with all installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will. VMs are stateful. The only thing that might change (depending on the setup) is the internal\external IP addresses.

Azure even provides [auto shutdown feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-auto-shutdown-for-vms-using-azure-resource-manager/), to save you some clicking.